# Modal shows but closes immediately in c# webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, modal-dialog

I want to show a modal window in webforms. The following code is from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal), which works fine, but in webforms it behaves differently. The modal did show up, but closed immediately.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="modal.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

   <asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" type="button"  />
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn1" >Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {

        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
    &nbsp;
    </div>

    </form>

       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its because its a webform it will try to submit the page, basically is reloads the page with the data submitted from the form, which is why it appears then disappears

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned its because you are using a `<form>` tag, when you press a button it will try to submit the form, there by reloading the page. In order to prevent it from submitting one way around it is to `return false` on your `onclick` functions

```
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {

    modal.style.display = "block";
    return false;
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you don't need it on the `span.onclick` function

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign server-side control like this, in javascript. Change your code.

```
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById('<%=myBtn.ClientID%>');

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {

        modal.style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Did Find a way. a post back is the cause of modal exit. solution is to enclose it with update panel and the problem is solved.